# Magic method to make class work as list index?

Tags: python

I can use a boolean as a list index:

```
isTrue = True
print ('No','Yes')[isTrue]  -> 'Yes'
```

but if I define a class,

```
class YeaOrNay(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = bool(val)

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.val

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.val)

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Nay','Yea')[self.val]
```

and try to use it the same way:

```
isTrue = YeaOrNay(True)
print ('No','Yes')[isTrue]
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not YeaOrNay
```

I can work around it,

```
print ('No','Yes')[int(isTrue)]  ->  'Yes'
```

but I would really like to know if there is some magic class method I can add to YeaOrNay to make it 'just work'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, `bool` is a subclass of `int`.  That's why you can use a `bool` as an index of the tuple.  However, `YeaOrNea` is clearly neither and thus the error.  If you insist on using this object as an index to a tuple, subclass `int` <s>(or `bool`)</s> to trick it to make it work.

```
class YeaOrNea(int):
    ...
```

Otherwise do it the right way.

```
print('Yes' if isTrue else 'No')
```

Comment: According to help(bool) "The class bool is a subclass of the class int, and cannot be subclassed." I could subclass int - and that's probably what I'll end up doing; I had just hoped for a duck-typing shortcut. Regarding the "right" way - what I am actually working on is a many-state finite automaton for report parsing; I just cut it down to the simplest possible example ;-)

Comment: Ah, ok so subclassing `bool` is not an option then.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simple is better than complex.

```
yes_or_no = {True: 'Yeah', False: 'No way'}
print yes_or_no[1==1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [**getitem**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). This does make your code harder to read though so I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Comment: This would be useful if I made a custom list or tuple type (one which recognizes YeaOrNay values as indexes); but I'd really prefer to know how to change YeaOrNay to make it work with vanilla lists, tuples, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. The attribute of the list or tuple or whatever is what's accessed. Not that of `YeaOrNay`.

Answer (score 0):

True = 1 and False = 0 so those can be used for indices

addressing 9000's comments, this relationship holds true in python 2.6.1:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> True == 2
False
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 1
False
>>> False == 0
True
```

Comment: Since Python 2.5 this is not exactly so.

Comment: (True is 1) is False.  True is a value equivalent to one but of a different type, just like 1.0.

Comment: See, `int(True) == 1` and `bool(1) == True`, you're right. The thing is that since 2.5 you need to _explicitly_ make this cast unless context assumes an implicit cast, like in `if`. The `==` operator does the cast for you, the `[]` does not. The same way `print(None)` implicitly casts `None` to `str`, so it's the same as `print('None')`, but `foo[None]` and `foo['None']` are different beasts.